# Android: Reordering Lists like playlists in the media player

Tags: android

I need to implement reordering of ListView rows like in media player. I found a lot of solutions, but most of them is hard to implement and they are 2 years old. Is there any fresh ideas and examples how to implement that ?

P.S: I should support API 10

Comment: I dont know what media player you mean but for reorder list view rows you must implement some Comparator that will be compare rows objects on your conditions. Than you need call Collections.sort (yourObjects, yourComparator) and create or update your adapter with this objects.